# Call feature with input as JsonArray without throwing Karate exception due to cast issue

Tags: karate

I am facing an issue where if I call feature with the following approach then it throws KarateException

```
javascript evaluation failed: x.action(x), com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray

* def result = call read('abcCommon.feature') { action : "start", input : ["X","Y"]}
```

In abcCommon.feature

```
Scenario: 
* def x = Java.Type('com.x')
* def status = x.action('#(input)')
```

My action method is reading the input as String and then parses the string to JsonArray and returns the string back to feature file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid embedded expression: `x.action('#(input)')`. Please read the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

In fact, you should just do this:  `x.action(input)` if `input` is already a valid variable in scope.

By the way your example is very incomplete and I am making some assumptions.

Comment: I realized my mistake. Thank you . Most of the example always talked about access the passed parameter with embedded impression in json as '#()' rather than just accessing it directly. I didn't realized that since its a shared scope the variable will be valid in scope.